# How to index columns into a single variable within code

Tags: r

I'm trying to extract landcover values within neighborhoods across all years, however, the problem occures in this line of code:

```
map(~ count(., landcover = value))
---------------------------------------
lc_extract_pred <- landcover[[paste0("y", 2019)]] %>% 
  exact_extract(r_cells, progress = FALSE)

    value    coverage_fraction
4     12       0.0005232538
9     12        0.1390771568
10    12        0.7728050947
```

Where `value` renames the column when I select a single year, however, when I try select multiple years the columns are named like this:

```
lc_extract_pred <- landcover[[paste0("y", 2010:2019)]] %>% 
  exact_extract(r_cells, progress = FALSE)

 y2010 y2011 y2012 y2013 y2014 y2015 y2016 y2017 y2018 y2019 coverage_fraction
4     12    12    12    12    12    12    12    12    12    12      0.0005232538
9     12    12    12    12    12    12    12    12    12    12      0.1390771568
10    12    12    12    12    12    12    12    12    12    12      0.7728050947
```

It's more of a question about, what should I place in the `landcover=`  part of the code.
It should come out like this:

```
lc_extract_pred <- landcover[[paste0("y", 2019)]] %>% 
  exact_extract(r_cells, progress = FALSE) %>% 
  map(~ count(., landcover = value)) %>% 
  tibble(id = r_cells$id, data = .) %>% 
  unnest(data)

#working example of single year
      id landcover     n
   <int>     <int> <int>
 1     1        12    29
 2     2        12    29
 3     3        12    29
 4     4        12    29
 5     5        12    29
 6     6         5     1
 7     6         9     2
 8     6        10     1
 9     6        12    24
10     6        14     1
# ...
```

Here is the code I am using and to make it easier, you can just run as is, although the final code to reproduce the one above does take a while:

```
library(sf)
library(raster)
library(exactextractr)
library(viridis)
library(tidyverse)
# resolve namespace conflicts
select <- dplyr::select
map <- purrr::map
projection <- raster::projection

dir.create("data", showWarnings = FALSE)

file1 <- "modis_mcd12q1_umd_2010.tif"
file2 <- "modis_mcd12q1_umd_2011.tif"
file3 <- "modis_mcd12q1_umd_2012.tif"
file4 <- "modis_mcd12q1_umd_2013.tif"
file5 <- "modis_mcd12q1_umd_2014.tif"
file6 <- "modis_mcd12q1_umd_2015.tif"
file7 <- "modis_mcd12q1_umd_2016.tif"
file8 <- "modis_mcd12q1_umd_2017.tif"
file9 <- "modis_mcd12q1_umd_2018.tif"
file10 <- "modis_mcd12q1_umd_2019.tif"
file11 <- "data_bcr.gpkg"

if (!file.exists(file.path("data", file1))) {
  download.file(paste0("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/lime-n/data/main/", file1),
                file.path("data", file1), mode = "wb")
}

if (!file.exists(file.path("data", file2))) {
  download.file(paste0("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/lime-n/data/main/", file2),
                file.path("data", file2), mode = "wb")
}
if (!file.exists(file.path("data", file3))) {
  download.file(paste0("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/lime-n/data/main/", file3),
                file.path("data", file3), mode = "wb")
}
if (!file.exists(file.path("data", file4))) {
  download.file(paste0("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/lime-n/data/main/", file4),
                file.path("data", file4), mode = "wb")
}
if (!file.exists(file.path("data", file5))) {
  download.file(paste0("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/lime-n/data/main/", file5),
                file.path("data", file5), mode = "wb")
}
if (!file.exists(file.path("data", file6))) {
  download.file(paste0("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/lime-n/data/main/", file6),
                file.path("data", file6), mode = "wb")
}
if (!file.exists(file.path("data", file7))) {
  download.file(paste0("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/lime-n/data/main/", file7),
                file.path("data", file7), mode = "wb")
}
if (!file.exists(file.path("data", file8))) {
  download.file(paste0("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/lime-n/data/main/", file8),
                file.path("data", file8), mode = "wb")
}
if (!file.exists(file.path("data", file9))) {
  download.file(paste0("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/lime-n/data/main/", file9),
                file.path("data", file9), mode = "wb")
}
if (!file.exists(file.path("data", file10))) {
  download.file(paste0("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/lime-n/data/main/", file10),
                file.path("data", file10), mode = "wb")
}
if (!file.exists(file.path("data", file11))) {
  download.file(paste0("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/lime-n/data/main/", file11),
                file.path("data", file11), mode = "wb")
}

landcover <- list.files("data/modis", "^modis_mcd12q1_umd", 
                        full.names = TRUE) %>% 
  stack()

landcover <- names(landcover) %>% 
  str_extract("(?<=modis_mcd12q1_umd_)[0-9]{4}") %>% 
  paste0("y", .) %>% 
  setNames(landcover, .)
landcover

bcr <- read_sf("data/data_bcr.gpkg")
st_crs(bcr) <-  paste("+proj=sinu +lon_0=0 +x_0=0 +y_0=0","+a=6371007.181 +b=6371007.181 +units=m +no_defs")

neighborhood_radius <- 5 * ceiling(max(res(landcover))) / 2
agg_factor <- round(2 * neighborhood_radius / res(landcover))

r <- raster(landcover) %>% 
  aggregate(agg_factor) 
r <- bcr %>% 
  st_transform(crs = projection(r)) %>% 
  rasterize(r, field = 1) %>% 
  # remove any empty cells at edges
  trim()

r_centers <- rasterToPoints(r, spatial = TRUE) %>% 
  st_as_sf() %>% 
  transmute(id = row_number())
r_cells <- st_buffer(r_centers, dist = neighborhood_radius)
####################################################################
###################################################################
lc_extract_pred <- landcover[[paste0("y", 2010:2019)]] %>% 
  exact_extract(r_cells, progress = FALSE) %>% 
  map(~ count(., landcover = value)) %>% 
  tibble(id = r_cells$id, data = .) %>% 
  unnest(data)
```

Comment: please provide a *minimal, self contained, reproducible example* that generates the error and illustrates the problem. You can use code or data that ships with R, but do not refer to files that we do not have or would need to be downloaded.

Comment: I'll get back to you and see what I can cook up for this

Comment: Realised there's no other way of doing this, other than selecting all the columns individually by year in the `count` part of the code. Then taking the `mean` value across all of these years and naming the final value as `landcover`.